# How to detect shape of an object using multiple images?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0, 3d-reconstruction

I have two side views ( say Left & Right) of an object. How to get the shape or size of the object using the 2 (if not multiple) images.

Is there any geometric constraints methods or feature recognition methods to do so?

The below are sample left & right views of the object

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to reconstruct object 3D size, you have to derive mathematical model for stereo system.

If you are using fixed camera for taking pictures, structure from motion technique seems to be good solution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion

Since openCV 3.0 implementation is included in library:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d7c/tutorial_table_of_content_sfm.html

Have fun!